# Prestashop: Get order details when order status is changed to “shipped”

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I need to get order details when order statut is changed to "shipped" by admin, to post them to a third party application with api.
I am using Prestashop V 1.7.7.0
I need help please. Thanks

```
    $city_cl = $_GET['????????'];
    $state_cl = $_GET['????????'];
    $address_cl = $_GET['????????'];
    $tel_2_cl = $_GET['????????'];
    $products = $_GET['????????'];
    $Quantity = $_GET['????????'];
    $cod = $_GET['????????'];
    $note = $_GET['????????'];

    $Url_str = 'http://example.com/api/set_parcel_post.php?id=123&tel_cl='.$tel_cl.'&name_lastname_cl='.$name_lastname_cl.'&city_cl='.$city_cl.'&state_cl='.$state_cl.'&address_cl='.$address_cl.'&tel_2_cl='.$tel_2_cl.'&products='.$products.'&cod='.$cod.'&Quantity='.$Quantity.'&note='.$note;

    $json = file_get_contents($Url_str);
    $result = json_decode($json);
```

I need help please. Thanks

Comment: Can you develop a module? If so look at the documentation and find the correct hook under order status section. Then hook a module to that particular action and you are done.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, can i insert my code directly in the core files? so i need to know which file exactly and how to get order details. Thanks.

Comment: If  the only solution is to develop a module, i am beginner and i need to know how to do that please and how to get order details in the module please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a super siple module that acts as you need, the last method is called when the order status changed (after the saving process).
You have to follow the guide on how to create and install a module ([here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/introduction/)) and call the appropriate hook (list [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/))

```
<?php  
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;

class OrderChanger extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'orderchanger';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Stackoverflow user';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Order changer');
        $this->description = $this->l('a description');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
    }
    
    public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

        if (!parent::install() ||
                !$this->registerHook('actionOrderStatusPostUpdate')
            )
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    
    
    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    public function hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate($params)
    {
        $order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);
        //do the stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your reply @Jack, i still need how to get these parameters please $city_cl, $state_cl, $address_cl, $tel_2_cl, $products, $Quantity, $cod, $note. please

Comment: What i am missing? :
`public function hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate($params)
    {
        if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 13)
        {
   $order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);
   $address = new Address((int)$order->id_address_delivery);
   $customer = new Customer((int)($address->id_customer));
   $country = new Country((int)($address->id_country));
   $state = new Country((int)($address->id_state)); `
I need to get country name and state name and products description please.

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, you have to follow the guide for the installation process.
What are you doing for retrieving informations seems ok.
Please, follow the guide and don't ask people to code for you.